# What set GRIDGAIN_HOME variable when embedding GridGain into another application

Tags: gridgain

What value set the environment variable GRIDGAIN_HOME when embedding GridGain into another application?

Currently I'm not defining it, the application is working fine but the in the log there's the following warning:

```
WARN  org.gridgain.grid.util.typedef.G - Failed to detect GridGain installation 
home. It was neither provided in GridConfiguration nor it could be detected 
from GRIDGAIN_HOME system property or environmental variable.
```

Can I just ignore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this warning can be ignored.